# Realworld java app using kilim framework

Tags: java, concurrency, message-passing

Is there any realworld app using [kilim](http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/) message-passing framework?

Answer (score 2):

[Erjang](https://github.com/trifork/erjang/wiki)